# Why is locale causing std::ostringstream to get slower as I use more threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, libc++, ostringstream

I'm building some formatted strings using `std::ostringstream`. When running on a single thread, code profiling shows no bottle neck caused by `std::ostringstream`.

[image: Code Profiling with a single thread]

When I start using more threads, `std::ostringstream` slows down due to `std::__1::locale::locale`.

[image: Code Profiling with two threads]

This gets worse and worse as more threads are used.

[image: Code Profiling with three threads]

I'm not performing any thread synchronization explicitly but I suspect something inside `std::__1::locale::locale` is causing my threads to block which gets worse as I use more threads. It's the difference between a single thread taking ~30 seconds and 10 threads taking 10 minutes.

The code is in question is small but called many times,

```
static std::string to_string(const T d) {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << d;

    return stream.str();
}
```

When I change it to avoid constructing a new `std::ostringstream` every time,

```
thread_local static std::ostringstream stream;
const std::string clear;

static std::string to_string(const T d) {
    stream.str(clear);
    stream << d;

    return stream.str();
}
```

I recover multithreaded performance but single thread performance suffers. What can I do to avoid this problem? The strings built here never need to be human readable. They are only used so that I can work around the lack of a hash function for `std::complex`. Is there away to avoid localization when building formatted strings?

```
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

thread_local std::map<std::string, void *> cache;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::vector<std::thread> threads(i);
        for (auto &t : threads) {
            t = std::thread([] () -> void {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                    std::ostringstream stream;
                    stream << std::complex<double> (static_cast<double> (j));
                    cache[stream.str()] = reinterpret_cast<void *> (&j);
                }
            });
        }
        for (auto &t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
        
        const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end =
                  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        const auto total_time = end - start;
        const std::chrono::nanoseconds total_time_ns =
                  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds> (total_time);

        if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()               << " ns"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000.0        << " μs"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000000.0     << " ms"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 60000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000000000.0  << " s"   << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 3600000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/60000000000.0 << " min" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/3600000000000 << " h"   << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running on an 10 core (8 performance, 2 efficiency)Apple M1 produces the output. Build setting are using the standard Xcode defaults. For a debug build the timings are

```
3.90096 s

4.15853 s

4.48616 s

4.843 s

6.15202 s

8.14986 s

10.6319 s

12.7732 s

16.7492 s

19.9288 s
```

For a Release build, the timings are

```
844.28 ms

1.23803 s

2.05088 s

3.39994 s

7.43743 s

9.53968 s

11.2953 s

12.6878 s

20.3917 s

24.1944 s
```

Comment: I think I'd need to see a [mre] to get some ideas about what could make 10 threads that slower than 1. How many processors does your machine have? Btw, if this is only to make a string out of `std::complex<T>`s in order to be able to hash them, there are far more efficient ways.

Comment: Because of rounding errors, I'm not sure that hashing `std::complex` (or indeed any floating point type) makes much sense anyway.  What do you plan to use it for?

Comment: @PaulSanders rounding errors don't matter here.

Comment: @user1139069 Compare your hashing of `std::complex`s with [this](https://godbolt.org/z/PTszKodhc). Does it perform any better than using `ostringstream`s + `std::hash<std::string>`? It's not _a good hashing function_ but neither is the one you have now and I don't think you'll get more collisions with my version.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why `<< 1`? (just curious)

Comment: @PaulSanders Just so that `A, B` will produce a different result than `B, A`. Not very scientific :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh right.  Operator precedence lol

Comment: Depending on the platform, I seem to vaguely remember that there's a way to disable per-thread locales.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm hashing several different types of items into the same map. I'm building a tree structure of math operations and I want to ensure that sub trees are only built once and reused. I need to make sure that the hash for constant node with a complex number is different than the hash for sqrt node or an array node, etc... Building the strings first is a simple way to ensure get compatible hash between all these different things.

Comment: @user1139069 I'm looking but I don't see where you've stated what compiler options you used to build the program, more to the point, optimization settings.  If you are running a "debug" or non-optimized build, the timings are meaningless.

Comment: Is the stream using the "C" locale?

Comment: Fortunately, NaNs always compare as != anything (even themselves) so the minor detail that there are lots of representation for NaN doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: @user1139069 _"I'm hashing several different types of items into the same map"_ - Ok, I'd only use the stringstream-based version as a very last resort. Make hashing specializations for the types you know will be used.  You can't however _"make sure that the hash for constant node with a complex number is different than the hash for sqrt node etc"_. Hashes have collisions which is why you need to check for equality of the hashed objects if the hash values are equal. Btw, here's a slightly improved version of [hashing of `std::complex`s](https://godbolt.org/z/YYxKv5Eev).

Comment: If you absolutely need a string-based hash, you could try using `sprintf`.  Maybe that doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some digging for alternatives, the [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) notes

> `std::to_string` relies on the current locale for formatting purposes, and therefore concurrent calls to `std::to_string` from multiple threads may result in partial serialization of calls. C++17 provides `std::to_chars` as a higher-performance locale-independent alternative.

Using `std::to_chars` in the minimum example instead results in much better performance to what I was expecting for an embarrassingly parallel code.

```
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <charconv>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

thread_local std::map<std::string, void *> cache;
thread_local std::map<std::string, void *> cache2;

void stream() {
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::vector<std::thread> threads(i);
        for (auto &t : threads) {
            t = std::thread([] () -> void {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                    std::ostringstream stream;
                    stream << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
                    stream << std::complex<double> (static_cast<double> (j));
                    cache[stream.str()] = reinterpret_cast<void *> (&j);
                }
            });
        }
        for (auto &t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
        
        const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end =
                  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        const auto total_time = end - start;
        const std::chrono::nanoseconds total_time_ns =
                  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds> (total_time);

        if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()               << " ns"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000.0        << " μs"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000000.0     << " ms"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 60000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000000000.0  << " s"   << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 3600000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/60000000000.0 << " min" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/3600000000000 << " h"   << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void to_chars() {
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::vector<std::thread> threads(i);
        const size_t max_digits = std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10;
        for (size_t k = 0, ke = threads.size(); k < ke; k++) {
            threads[k] = std::thread([] () -> void {
                std::array<char, 36> buffer;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                    char *end = std::to_chars(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), static_cast<double> (j),
                                              std::chars_format::general, max_digits).ptr;
                    cache2[std::string(buffer.data(), end)] = reinterpret_cast<void *> (&j);
                }
            });
        }
        for (auto &t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
        
        const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end =
                  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        const auto total_time = end - start;
        const std::chrono::nanoseconds total_time_ns =
                  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds> (total_time);

        if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()               << " ns"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000.0        << " μs"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 1000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000000.0     << " ms"  << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 60000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/1000000000.0  << " s"   << std::endl;
        } else if (total_time_ns.count() < 3600000000000) {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/60000000000.0 << " min" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << total_time_ns.count()/3600000000000 << " h"   << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    stream();
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    to_chars();
    return 0;
}
```

Results in timings of

```
854.078 ms

1.3472 s

2.26556 s

3.61298 s

7.55469 s

9.29697 s

11.321 s

12.6926 s

19.607 s

24.4866 s

-----------------------------------------------------------
403.037 ms

416.532 ms

432.433 ms

437.869 ms

450.775 ms

458.693 ms

473.683 ms

498.53 ms

528.434 ms

560.239 ms
```

Code profiling confirms the may string hashes are no longer the largest bottleneck.

[image: Code profiling using std::to_char and 10 threads]